# Restore Video from Audio in Premiere

Tags: video, premiere

Say I add a bunch of Audio/Video clips to a sequence, then replace the video with an After Effects composition, that was currupted. Premiere was closed and re-opened. The audio is still there but the video is missing.

**Is there any way to restore the video to the audio clip that was deleted?**

I tried this [solution](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13489/adobe-premiere-restore-audio-to-a-v-clip-after-deleting) for deleted audio, but it didn't work for deleted video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the audio track was from a video clip in premiere, and was not replaced by the after effects comp, it should still be present in your project, and you should just be able to use the [Match Frame](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/playing-assets.html#match_a_frame_with_its_source) command to find and resync the video to your audio.

Even with thirty clips, it shouldn't take that long if you use keyboard shortcuts.

Something like:

Select the first piece of audio in your timeline.
Set your in point on your timeline "i"
Press "f" to match frame
Press "." to replace the video at the correct point

(and repeat)